# How do I fix iTunes could not copy unknown error (-5000)?

Tags: iphone, itunes

I got this error trying to sync from my Macbook Pro (OSX Yosemite, 10.10.5) to my iPhone SE:

> iTunes could not copy "The Song Remains the Same" to the iPhone "Dan's Phone" because an unknown error occurred (-5000).

Oddly, the problem didn't occur with my previous iPhone 5s.  How do I fix it?

Comment: I have the exact same issue - except that my ITunes is on a Windows Laptop. Can you please help me in terms of what changes I need to do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: On windows, I imagine the basic process would be similar. Note the song that fails, assess it's permissions and other attributes, and then correct it's permissions.  I haven't used windows in ~10 years though, so can't offer specific help.  You may do better opening a new question, and you'll need to provide more information for anyone to help you (i.e. windows version, etc).

Answer (score 1):

The solution was simple - it was a permissions problem.  On the Mac, here are the steps I took to fix:

- Note the song that fails, on my case it was a Zeppelin song.
- Using the terminal, cd to the directory containing the song
- Run `ls -la` and note the owner/permissions of the file that fails, in my case it was an alternate username I was using at one point, let's say that username is paulhewson, and your real username is hewson
- Run `sudo find . -user paulhewson` from the top level music directory (~/Music), this shows all the music that is owned by this alternate user
- This command will change the owner to your normal username: `sudo find . -user paulhewson -exec chown hewson {} +`

I suspect this error could result from any sort of permission problem, in some cases maybe read-only or locked files, in which case you'd want to chmod or unlock the files.  If there are multiple types of permission problems, you may need to repeat this process a few times.  Might be easier to chmod/chown everything in music, but I tried to avoid that so I didn't cause other issues.

Credit to this question for help with the find command to change ownership:
[Change owner for all files owned by x](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/56025/change-owner-for-all-files-owned-by-x)